# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Configuration' even though IntelliSense suggests otherwise

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, windows-services, .net-6.0

I am having a strange problem here. I created a Worker project in order to create a Windows Service in .NET 6 following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service). I want to read the settings from `appsettings.json` so I added the following code:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "My Service";
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        var settings = new ScriptOptions(); // ScriptOptions is just a POCO class
        services.Configuration.Bind(settings);

        services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
    })
    .Build();
```

As you can see, IntelliSense seems to recognize there is `Configuration` property in `services` (instance of `IServiceCollection`).

[image]

However, the code wouldn't compile with this error:

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Configuration' and no accessible extension method 'Configuration' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What package am I missing? My project currently has:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They fixed [the bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/63339). To access `Configuration` or other `IHostBuilderContext` members, use this overload:

```cs
    .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
    {
        var settings = new ScriptOptions();
        ctx.Configuration.Bind(settings);

        services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
    })
```

---

**Original answer:**

Seem to be an IntelliSense bug, I reported it <del>[here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6918)</del> <del>[on VS Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IntelliSense-confused-by-Action-overlo/10116304)</del> [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/63339). If you encounter the same problem, please upvote it.

Looks like somehow IntelliSense was confused by the other overload. Indeed [IServiceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) does NOT have `Configuration` property, but [HostBuilderContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) does.

`ConfigureServices` has another overload that expose both parameters. This fixes the problem:

```
    // Add ctx parameter
    .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
    {
        var settings = new ScriptOptions();
        ctx.Configuration.Bind(settings);

        services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
    })
```

Answer (score 17):

Just install nuget package "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions"
it will solve the problem, it has "Configure" extension method.

Comment: You should not need that package. You only need to use the correct extension method. See my answer.

Comment: I have installed "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" package and it works fine, may you have another solution, but mine is the easiest.

Comment: this is fix to me.

Answer (score 2):

Add "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" package.

in program class add to get secret.json:

```
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddUserSecrets<Program>().Build();
```

or get appsetting.json

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(appsettings.json, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
```

Get your secrets:

```
configuration["ServiceBus:CONNECTION_STRING"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is disagreement here between the 2 options is because there are actually 2 methods.

#### Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions has:

```
Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
```

#### Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions has:

```
Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<TOptions> configureOptions)
```

Note that the second parameter is different!  Also they seem to come from different NuGet packages notably:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions

and

- Microsoft.Extensions.Options

Answer (score 0):

Just need to install NuGet package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options' to your project.